# How do I get 100000 to be like 100,000

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const renderCommas = (number) => {
    return number >= 1000 ? `${Number.parseFloat((number).toFixed(3))}` : number;
};
```

Comment: `toFixed` should be only used for decimals, not for number localization.

Comment: what is your suggestion then

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2901102/438992 etc. It's usually worth searching before asking.

Comment: @Rover33 Using some terms from my previous comment I was able to google `toLocaleString()`

Comment: Here is the MDN link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Comment: Meta: I don't think it's cool to downvote correct answers just to punish them for answering dupes. Just comment and move on; responsible users will delete their answers.

Comment: I agree with @DaveNewton. Downvote tells the answer is wrong. Like I felt. :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use toLocaleString()

```js
a = 100000
console.log(a.toLocaleString());
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use the following code to format a number with a comma:

```
var num       = 100000;
var formatted = num.toLocaleString(undefined);

console.log(formatted);
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's unclear to me why you're advocating for `undefined` as the parameter to `toLocaleString`, and I think without any explanation, it's an incomplete answer.